# MBOX to PST file converter

Tags: email, gmail, outlook

I'm looking for a free or open source software able to convert Gmail MBOX email archives to Outlook PST archives.
It can be a Windows 10 or MacOS X software, I'm also open to x86/x64 Linux command line tools.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe try the manual method described here, using Thunderbird: http://easytechtools.com/2016/09/28/mbox-to-pst-file-conversion/

Comment: Interesting method, it would be nice to have a simpler method to convert it though.

Comment: There are multiple software available to convert Gmail email archive MBOX file to PST file, but no free tool available. If you want to convert MBOX archive to PST archive in Windows 10 so you can try this tool- [https://datahelpsoftware.com/mbox/pst/](https://datahelpsoftware.com/mbox/pst/). The demo is available free of cost.

Answer (score 2):

There is a free [Convert MBOX to PST](https://www.outlookfreeware.com/en/products/all/OutlookConvertMBOX2PST) utility available for Windows and Outlook. Please note that I'm one of the developers of this tool.

Comment: Interesting tool, easy to use.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps to convert Gmail MBOX to Outlook:

1. Create a Gmail for connecting to Outlook
2. Add your  Gmail account to Outlook
3. Copy and paste your Gmail messages to your desktop
4. Copy your Gmail to your Office 365 mailbox
5. Remove your Gmail account from Outlook

Visit this MS link for more information: [Import Gmail to Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/import-gmail-to-outlook-20fdb8f2-fed8-4b14-baf0-bf04b9c44bf7)